# fundamental identity proof linear models

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-regression

Prove the equation
$||y - \bar{y}\boldsymbol{1}||^2 = ||\hat{y} - \bar{y}\boldsymbol{1}||^2 + ||y - \hat{y}||^2$.

\begin{align}
    y &= \begin{bmatrix}
           y_{1} \\
           y_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           y_{m}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

\begin{align}
    1 &= \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           1 \\
           \vdots \\
           1
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}
\begin{align}
    \bar{y}\boldsymbol{1} &= \begin{bmatrix}
           \bar{y} \\
           \bar{y}  \\
           \vdots \\
           \bar{y} 
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}
\begin{align}
    \hat{y} &= \begin{bmatrix}
            \hat{y_{1}} \\
           \hat{y_{2}} \\
           \vdots \\
           \hat{y_{3}}
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}
I tried proving $(\hat{y} - \bar{y}\boldsymbol{1}).(y - \hat{y})=0$ but not sure how to simplify.

Comment: You did not specify the expression of $\hat{y}$. Also, did you try to look at the equation(s) used to compute $\hat{y}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed $(\hat{y} - \bar{y} \mathbf{1})^\top (y - \hat{y}) = 0$.
To show this you need to use the properties of $\hat{y}$.

---

Abstractly, $\hat{y}$ is the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto the column space of $X$ (the design matrix), and $X$ is assumed to contain $\mathbf{1}$ as a column.
An important property of the orthogonal projection is that $\hat{y} \in \text{colspace}(X)$ and $y - \hat{y}$ is orthogonal to everything in $\text{colspace}(X)$.
This first fact implies $\hat{y} - \bar{y} \mathbf{1} \in C(X)$ and the second fact thus implies the desired statement $(\hat{y} - \bar{y} \mathbf{1})^\top (y - \hat{y}) = 0$.

---

More concretely, you may write $\hat{y} = X \hat{\beta}$ where $\hat{\beta}$ satisfies $$X^\top X \hat{\beta} = X^\top y. \tag{$*$}$$
Thus $X^\top \hat{y} = X^\top y$, and now use the fact that $X$ contains $\mathbf{1}$ as a column to conclude $$\mathbf{1}^\top \hat{y} = \mathbf{1}^\top y.$$
Similarly, you can use ($*$) to show
$$\hat{y}^\top (y - \hat{y}) = 0.$$
Combining these last two facts yields the desired equality
$(\hat{y} - \bar{y} \mathbf{1})^\top (y - \hat{y}) = 0$.